# null value is there in the column how to combine

Tags: sql, oracle11g

fname   lname        id

```
a       null    101
null     p      101
 b       null   102
null      q     102
c         null  103
null      r     103
```

i want output like this :`

fname   lname     id

```
a    p       101

b     q      102

c     r      103
```

Comment: How are the (first column of) `id`s in your desired output related to the data in your table?

Comment: Why does fname 'c' go with lname 'q' instead of with lname 'r'?

Comment: Can you rely on each row of your table having exactly one of `fname` and `lname` null?

Comment: Can you rely on there being exactly one non-null `fname` and one non-null `lname` for each `empid`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger   i have updated the value and formatting of the table please check it out

Answer (score 2):

Are those really the results you want?  they don't make since you now have id 1 repeated twice and your agregation is supposed to combine 101 with 101 but then 102 with 103 and 102 with 103????  if you just messed up your results simply take the aggregate.

```
SELECT
    MIN(id) AS id
    ,MAX(fname) as fname
    ,MAX(lname) as lname
    ,empid
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY
    empid
```

Comment: @user6754455 if my answer or another worked for you please consider accepting it so others know you got what you needed and reputation points are assigned. thanks http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

simply join the table to itself - one copy for the fname and one for the lname

```
SELECT
  a.fname,
  b.lname,
  a.empid
FROM yourTable AS a
INNER JOIN yourTable AS b
  ON a.empid = b.empid
  AND a.fname IS NOT NULL
  AND b.lname IS NOT NULL
```